# Separating PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine

I apologize for asking such a beginner question, but i'm unsure on where else I could go to get such help. I'm currently creating a php website using GoggleApp Engine. I've created a very simple form using html in the same file as my PHP. Now, I know this isn't good practice, so I want to break up my html into it's own file. My only question is, how would I re-write this code assuming that my html is in it's own file?

[image]

Comment: You should read about template engines and their use - probably Twig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to place your PHP code in the same file as your HTML code. However, if you are going to duplicate code, it would be best to have separate files (maybe say a header and footer file).

That way you can use require_once("header.php") and require_once("footer.php") in each file that wants to use the top and bottom portions of your code.

As Sven mentioned, you can look into templating. You can also look into coding habits such as MVC (Model View Controller) and similar methods.

Comment: I previously wrote a website using go language that used func handlers. Is there something like this in PHP?